# How can I easily win at 'Fun Fun Island'?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

When `Fun Fun Island` is finally opened, there is great potential to earn a lot of rupees relatively quick and easy.  If you get a perfect score, you could earn `480` rupees in one shot (`-20` to play, `+500` to win) and the game is over in about 40 seconds with no thinking involved.

What are some strategies to help me win at this game easily?

Figuring out which way to go can be tough getting the timing right.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The majority of this game can be pretty easy.  Falling through the **Fortune Rings** and dodging the **Dodoh Balls** can be easily navigated once you know which paths are relatively safe and which ones should be avoided.  It's the landing that is the tough part.  I'll walk through these phases separately.  But first...

#### Control:

When free falling, the controller is pretty sensitive to your movements.  For this game, you *barely* need to tilt it to move in the direction you want, and you'll have plenty of time to move to the part of the screen you want without it getting out of control.  You shouldn't try to tilt more than 10 degrees, you shouldn't need to.

#### The fall:

First let's understand what you're up against.  There are **5 Fortune Rings** and **4 sets of Dodoh Balls** alternating starting with the rings.  We want to avoid the **Dodoh Balls** so here's how big each set is and how they move.

1. **4 Dodoh Balls** in a small square, rotating.
2. **1 Dodoh Ball** in the center, stationary.
3. **4 Dodoh Balls** in a larger square, rotating.
4. **3 Dodoh Balls** in a triangle, stationary.

Avoiding the stationary balls should be simple so I'll leave that to you.  However you have to be careful with the rotating ones.  My advice, *never* try to weave through the rotating balls (sets 1 and 3), always go through the middle.  You can risk it and try, but why make it harder on yourself?

[image: go in the middle of the rotating balls]

#### The landing:

*Ok this is where it gets tricky.  I have to admit though, this is not foolproof advice.  There is a degree of randomness in this game so it won't always be the same.  But, this should be very close every time.  The risk of playing this game is very small but the reward is so much bigger.  I can almost guarantee you will miss a lot here landing in the **Loser Space**, but I promise you'll win enough here too.*

At this point, I will assume you have a **10x** multiplier by getting all 5 rings.  **Dodoh** claims that the wheel slows down for every ring you get.  I don't know if that's really true or not, I can't tell the difference.  So I am assuming that the wheel should be rotating at roughly the same rate here.

First thing to note is the ground and how it looks like.  You should notice that there is a orange and yellow "star" each with 12 points.  I would look at these like they are clocks.  You'll need to use these as reference points to help you with this.  These "clocks" are mostly stationary.  You just need to be aware that the camera is actually rotating a little too.

[image: the "clocks"]

As far as I can tell, if you fall in the open stance (and not diving headfirst), the wheel will generally make almost a full rotation from when you hit the last **Fortune Ring** and you hit the ground; sometimes a little less, sometimes a little more, or it could just be my reaction time not being consistent.  I estimate 11/12 of a rotation based on the video I took.

Before you reach the last ring, find the **50 rupee** space and keep tabs on it's location relative to the clocks.  You'll also want to pay attention to where **Link** is relative to the ring so you can get ready.

When you finally reach the ring and you *hear* the sound of collecting it, find the point of the orange or yellow star that is closest to the middle of the space and keep track of that.  The region that between that point and the previous point of the same color is your target area to land in.

[image: the approach 1]
[image: the approach 2]

Also, remember that it will probably be rotating too.  At that point, it's just a matter of hitting your target and making any adjustments you can.  With any luck, the **50 rupee** space should come up right under you.  If you know you're behind, you could dive in headfirst (point the WiiMote straight down) and hope that will make up for it.

[image: finish]

Here's a video I recorded that you can analyze:

Comment: I totally agree with this, except that in my experience the wheel makes *exactly* a full rotation from when you hit the last ring, assuming you've reached a maximum 10x multiplier (and that you're falling at the standard rate, i.e. not diving headfirst). I've also noticed that with an 8x multiplier I need to account for an extra ~30˚ rotation

Comment: The wheel definitely slows down for each ring you get - drastically.  Try missing some rings and this should be pretty apparent.

Answer (score 0):

Walk to the 50 space, put a column of light, and when you hit the last ring AIM.

Answer (score -1):

About the fifth or so time I played fun fun island I stayed in the last ring and just landed without diving and hit the 50 rupee spot