# Do I need to go looking for the missing Fun Fun Island wheel?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

The owner of Fun Fun Island is very sad. It appears he has lost his wheel. I'd like to help him out. I suspect it fell somewhere in the Lanayru Desert, the closest surface world. **Do I need to go explicitly look for this wheel, or will it turn up in the normal course of my adventuring?**

(A generic hint about its location would be nice, too, before mentioning the specific location. Please markup hints as spoilers.)

Comment: Do you want a guide to how to find it posted? (I can mark it with spoilers if you like.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finding it is not a requirement to finish the game.  It just grants you access to the money making minigame that is covered in [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/38170/how-can-i-easily-win-at-fun-fun-island).  I would suggest getting it as it is an easy source of rupees with little to lose and a lot to gain with relative ease.

Unless you are a very throurough in searching every spot there is in a map for anything, you probably wouldn't see this in your normal, go-for-the-objective adventuring.  It's location is near a "hidden" chest and off the beaten path.

Hint:

> To reach it involves some ledge climbing and the help of a **Timeshift Stone**.

---

How to get it:

> When you first enter **Lanyru Desert** (after exiting the mine), there will be a **Timeshift Stone** nearby.  Hitting it will reveal some vines on a nearby wall that you may climb up.

> There will be a ledge that you can climb up to to reach another cliff on the other side of the little gorge.

> You will end up on a narrow land bridge where below you will see an isolated chest sittng by and the wheel at the end (in the corner).  You can't miss it.

Comment: The day after I posted this question, after receiving improvements to my sword's dowsing ability, I went back to Fun Fun Island and Fi gave me the ability to dowse for the wheel.  I found it in no time after that.

Answer (score 1):

It's a side quest, so it is entirely possible you may miss it, although eventually you will be able to dowse for it (you do have to complete a few other things first).