How do I get a large amount of rupees in The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword?
How do I collect a lot of rupees in The Legend of Zelda: Skyward Sword (Nintendo Switch version)?
I destroy all taps, barrels, etc. with my sword, but they are only dropping some green rupees and sometimes blue rupees. I can't imagine that I will earn enough rupees to buy all upgrades (health, etc.).
Is there any other, better way to get more rupees?

I'm pretty sure this is still applicable today. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/38170

Thanks, seems that it works, but maybe there is another way to earn some rupees :)
